# If statements not working (Time In and Time Out)

Tags: c, dev-c++

It seems that the if statements are not working.

For example, if I input `2405` in the "Time in" or "Time out" the if statements does not work or it does not execute the given statements inside the if(s).

As we know 2405 is larger than 2400 why it wont work? I have tried changing the logical operators but it wont work.

My compiler is DevC++ 4.9.9.2

Here is my source code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct record
{
       char computer_code[10];
       int time_in;
       int time_out;
       int time_consumed;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("computer.txt", "w");

    struct record comprec[50];

    int a=0;
    char ans;

    do
    {
        do
        {
              a++;
              printf("\n");
              printf("Computer code: ");
              scanf("%s", comprec[a].computer_code);

              printf("Time in: ");
              scanf("%d", &comprec[a].time_in);
              if(comprec[a].time_in<0000 || comprec[a].time_in>2400)
              {
                                   printf("Time in: ");
                                   scanf("%d", &comprec[a].time_in);
              }

              printf("Time out: ");
              scanf("%d", &comprec[a].time_out);
              if(comprec[a].time_out<0000 || comprec[a].time_out>2400)
              {
                                   printf("Time out: ");
                                   scanf("%d", &comprec[a].time_out);
              }

              if(comprec[a].time_in>comprec[a].time_out)
              {
                                   printf("Time in: ");
                                   scanf("%d", &comprec[a].time_in);
              }

              comprec[a].time_consumed = comprec[a].time_out-comprec[a].time_in;

              printf("\nTime consumed: %0.4d", comprec[a].time_consumed);
              fprintf(fp, "%s    %d  %d  %0.4d\n", comprec[a].computer_code, comprec[a].time_in, comprec[a].time_out, comprec[a].time_consumed);

        }while(a<1);

        printf("\nDo you want to input again?: ");
        scanf("%s", &ans);

    }while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My Inputs in the Program:

```
Computer code: COMP-001
Time in: 2405
Time in: 2406
Time out: 2407
Time out: 2408

Time consumed: 0002
Do you want to input again?: N
```

Expected Program:

```
Computer code: COMP-001
Time in: 2405
Time in: 2406
Time in: 1200
Time out: 2407
Time out: 2408
Time out: 1247

Time consumed: 0047
Do you want to input again?: N
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full input you give the program, and the full actual output the program produces, and also the *expected* output of the program.

Comment: You should also learn how to use a debugger, then you could step through the code line by line while seeing the values of all variables, and might better see what goes wrong and where.

Comment: Lastly, in the `time_out` check, you still print `time_in`. Is it supposed to be like that, or just a copy-paste error? Same with the comparison between `time_in` and `time_out`.

Comment: One trick for people who use C language is to make a printf whenever we have a value to go see what values we have.
But i agree with @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Besides your actual program asks two times for "Time in", so the if statement obviously works. As you don't check the second input again, you can now type whatever you want. In other words, `if` should become `while`

Comment: ^^ exactly.  do{get input} while input is bad;

Comment: `while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');` will not work as `ans` is a string.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thank you my program worked. One last question, my program here inputs "Time In" and the "Time Out" in an internet cafe in a 24-hour format of time. Is it possible to check if the entered minute is incorrect without separating the hour from minutes? For example: My input is 2269, we know that 22:69 does not exists and it must be 23:10 right? . So is it possible?

Comment: `if( time % 100 >= 60 ) { printf( "invalid time\n" ); } `

Comment: @IngoLeonhart Thank you again!

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Can I ask again? When I subract 0900(09:00) "Time Out" from 0859(08:59) "Time In" the "Time Consumed" becomes 0041 (41 Minutes) it was supposed to be 0001(1 Minute). How can I solve this without affecting equations like 1241 (Time Out) - 1200 (Time In) because the difference of that is also 41 but it is alright because it's true that the user consumed 41 minutes using the computer. Thanks.

Comment: For this you need to transform times into minutes like that: `minutes = (time / 100) * 60 + time % 100` and use the minutes for calculations.

Comment: Just spotted that you deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399133/airplane-seat-reservation-java-language), presumably because it acquired a couple of downvotes. Whilst it may well be too broad, it is very good practice to work with the feedback you receive (e.g. to clarify "doesn't work") as that will help you ask better questions in the future. The person who has answered so far, Alex, will also feel like he or she has not wasted their time and effort, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop asking Time-in and loop asking Time-out until they have been entered correctly. Your code only asks once again and then carries on with the wrong input.

```
    do {
          printf("Time in: ");
    } while (scanf("%d", &comprec[a].time_in)!=1
      || (comprec[a].time_in<0000 || comprec[a].time_in>2400));
```